# Forcing ResourceBundleViewResolver to load view.properties file from specific location

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is there a way to set a specific location where the `ResourceBundleViewResolver` should look for the `view.properties` files?

By specific location I mean somewhere not inside the classpath but anywhere in the file system / network resource.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be in `WEB-INF/classes`, it just has to be somewhere on the classpath, and `WEB-INF/classes` is usually the most convenient place.

If you want to put it somewhere else, then you're free to do so, as long as it's in the "root" on the classpath, e.g. inside a JAR under `WEB-INF/lib`.

Furthermore, it doesn't have to be called `views.properties`, it can be anything you like. Read the [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/ResourceBundleViewResolver.html#setBasename%28java.lang.String%29usage.) for `ResourceBundleViewResolver.setBaseName()`:

> Set a single basename, following
>   ResourceBundle  conventions. The
>   default is "views".
>
> ResourceBundle supports different
>   suffixes. For example, a base name of
>   "views" might map to ResourceBundle
>   files "views", "views_en_au" and
>   "views_de".
>
> Note that ResourceBundle names are
>   effectively classpath locations: As a
>   consequence, the JDK's standard
>   ResourceBundle treats dots as package
>   separators. This means that
>   "test.theme" is effectively equivalent
>   to "test/theme", just like it is for
>   programmatic java.util.ResourceBundle
>   usage.

So it can be anywhere in the classpath you like. `ResourceBundleViewResolver` is a lot more flexible than you're giving it credit for - it pays to read the documentation.

Comment: Ok, Maybe I didn't expressed the question the correct way, but I meant "specific path" that means, not inside the classpath but anywhere in the file system or any network resource. I also used the views.properties name because its the default name. I did read the doc, that's why I asked, because the doc doesn't mention a way to do that.

I edited the question to clarify.